# Adding a clear option to the drop down list using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down similar to this:

```
  <select>
     <option value=" " id="invisible" style="display:none;"></option>
     <option value="0">one</option>
     <option value="1">two</option>
     <option value="2">three</option>
     <option value="">clear</option>
  </select>
```

When I press 'clear' option, the drop down list should show nothing (even 'clear') but not delete any options inside i.e. nothing should show on the dropdown list until it is clicked.

Please advise.

Comment: I seriously doubt that this would be cross browser solution.

Comment: This should be possible, at least with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

just have an id for select and set value for option clear as 'clear'...

```
<option value='clear'>clear</option>
<select id="select">
```

then try this...

```
if($('#select').val() == 'clear'){
    $('#select).val('');
}
```

For javascript...

```
var value = document.getElementById('select');

if(value == 'clear'){
    document.getElementById('select').value = '';
}
```

might work...